# Spring Integration is wrapping the actual exception details when "409 conflict" is returned by web service

Tags: spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration in my project. When I execute a rest service using any REST client like "`POSTMAN`"(in one particular scenario), the following response is returned with the error code `409 conflict`

But when I try to execute the same rest service for the same scenario using `int-http:outbound-gateway`, I am getting the follwing error message in the log file:

```
2017-02-24 15:41:06,085 WARN  main [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate] PUT request for "http://10.193.244.136/awdServer/awd/services/v1/instances/2017-02-22-01.02.41.198440O01/parents/2017-02-13-04.28.17.304420T01" resulted in 409 (Conflict); invoking error handler
2017-02-24 15:41:06,085 WARN  main [org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean$MethodInvocationGateway] failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive
org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [http://10.193.244.136/awdServer/awd/services/v1/instances/2017-02-22-01.02.41.198440O01/parents/2017-02-13-04.28.17.304420T01]
                at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:398)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:148)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:148)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:148)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:131)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
                at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
                at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
                at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$ReplyForwardingMessageChannel.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:256)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$ReplyForwardingMessageChannel.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:249)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:148)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:167)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:131)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
                at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
                at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
                at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
                at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:149)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
                at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:134)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:148)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:148)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:131)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
                at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
                at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
                at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
                at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:149)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
                at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:150)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
                at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
                at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
                at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
                at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:149)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:361)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:274)
                at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:234)
                at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:208)
                at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:323)
                at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:286)
                at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:277)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
                at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.pqRelateAttachment(Unknown Source)
                at com.dsths.cs.awd.junits.PQRelateAttachmentTest.testPQRelateAttachmentTest(PQRelateAttachmentTest.java:31)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
                at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
                at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
                at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
                at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
                at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
                at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
                at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
                at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
                at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
                at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
                at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
                at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
                at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
                at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
                at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
                at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
                at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 409 Conflict
                at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:88)
                at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:532)
                at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:488)
                at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:460)
                at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:409)
                at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:372)
                ... 139 more
```

It appears that the response is suppressed/wrapped by the spring integration which consequently resulted in loss of the error message.

My requirement is to retrieve the actual error response message returned by the web service(in my case it is : `<message>Relationship already exists.</message>`).

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it say anything to you?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 409 Conflict
```

Exactly this exception is a result of the `DefaultResponseErrorHandler`.

So, having any Spring Integration error handling (or just regular `try...catch`) you can get `MessageHandlingException.getCause()` and extract a desired message via `HttpClientErrorException.getResponseBodyAsString()`.

Comment: Perfect!... +1 for eaplanation.